# How to compare two UIColor which have almost same shade or range in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, color-scheme, cgcolor

I have a condition in my app where user can choose 3 colors, but those colors should not match with each other, the problem is user can choose the similar color from the pallet for all 3 fields.

I'm trying below code, here color2 has slightly different value of 'green' than color1 :-

```
UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.4 blue:1 alpha:1];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.2 blue:1 alpha:1];

 if ([color1 isEqual:color2]) {
        NSLog(@"equals");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"not equal");
    }
```

output: 'not equal'
This is correct by logic because it compares RGB value but I want to check range of it, Let me know if anyone knows how to compare the similar colors.

Comment: Try `CGColorEqualToColor(<#CGColorRef color1#>, <#CGColorRef color2#>);`

Comment: Method has description :- "Two colors are equal if they have equal color spaces and numerically equal color components." It returns false, may be its unable to check color space, not sure.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need a *tolerance*, the value of which, only you can decide:

```
- (BOOL)color:(UIColor *)color1
isEqualToColor:(UIColor *)color2
withTolerance:(CGFloat)tolerance {

    CGFloat r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2;
    [color1 getRed:&r1 green:&g1 blue:&b1 alpha:&a1];
    [color2 getRed:&r2 green:&g2 blue:&b2 alpha:&a2];
    return
        fabs(r1 - r2) <= tolerance &&
        fabs(g1 - g2) <= tolerance &&
        fabs(b1 - b2) <= tolerance &&
        fabs(a1 - a2) <= tolerance;
}

...

UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.4 blue:1 alpha:1];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.2 blue:1 alpha:1];

if ([self color:color1 isEqualToColor:color2 withTolerance:0.2]) {
    NSLog(@"equals");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not equal");
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Though, I would probably use || instead of && as only one element needs to be different enough to create a whole new colour.

Comment: @DaveWood Sorry, I don't follow what you mean WRT `||`/`&&`.  The `return` statement will short-circuit as soon as soon as a colour falls outside of a tolerance.

Comment: You're right sorry. I jumped the gun as the version I was typing up was testing not equal (and not in a nice function like you did). :)

Comment: Beat me to it also, with a more complete answer!

Comment: although correct, this answer is way too complicated than what it needs to be. Mani answer below is easier & better

Comment: @SamB How is Mani's code different to the code provided by the OP, which is causing him problems?

Answer (score 13):

**trojanfoe**'s answer is great, here is a Swift version:

My suggestion: Create an extension on `UIColor` like so:

```
public extension UIColor{

    func isEqualToColor(color: UIColor, withTolerance tolerance: CGFloat = 0.0) -> Bool{

        var r1 : CGFloat = 0
        var g1 : CGFloat = 0
        var b1 : CGFloat = 0
        var a1 : CGFloat = 0
        var r2 : CGFloat = 0
        var g2 : CGFloat = 0
        var b2 : CGFloat = 0
        var a2 : CGFloat = 0

        self.getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
        color.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)

        return
            fabs(r1 - r2) <= tolerance &&
            fabs(g1 - g2) <= tolerance &&
            fabs(b1 - b2) <= tolerance &&
            fabs(a1 - a2) <= tolerance
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
// check if label's color is white
if label.textColor.isEqualToColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), /* optional */ withTolerance: 0.0){
    // if so, add shadow
    label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    label.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
}
```

Comment: I et tolerance default to 1e-6 :]

Answer (score 9):

You can use this function also.

```
UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.4 blue:1 alpha:1];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:(CGFloat)0.2 blue:1 alpha:1];

if (CGColorEqualToColor(color1.CGColor,color2.CGColor))
{
    //Two colors are same
}
```

Comment: This is not correct since it does not allow any tolerance.

Comment: It was working. But this may be outdated since 8 yrs old answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood clearly :

```
CGFloat *components1 = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor color1] CGColor]);
CGFloat *component1 = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor color2] CGColor]);
```

Then, you can compare the difference between the two colors using `components[0]` (red),`components[1]` (green), `components[2]` (blue) and `components[3]` alpha.
Decide what you wanna compare. Example :
`fabs(components1[1]-components2[1])`, or a mean between all theses differences, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`isEqualTo:` works when you initialize `UIColor` instance by passing `float` values

```
UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.4f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.2f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];

 if ([color1 isEqual:color2]) {
     NSLog(@"equals");
 }else {
     NSLog(@"not equal");
 }

 // This will print equals
```