# UIColor equality fails after storing it in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, uicolor

I am storing an `UIColor` in `NSUserDefaults`, and the problem that I am having is that a simple equality check fails (for my tests) when retrieving the color back. Can somebody explain why this fails?

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.922 green: 0.404 blue: 0.024 alpha: 1];
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"myColor"];

NSData *storedColorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
UIColor *restoredColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedColorData];

if ([color isEqual:restoredColor]) {
    NSLog(@"Same color");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not the same color");
}
```

The result will be "Not the same color". Quick looking in the debugger will show that the colors are identical (the RGB and alpha values).

Comment: isEqual: is a hash comparison. you need to compare the components of your color (red, green, blue, alpha) to determine if they are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare your UIColor like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed: (float)0.922 green: (float)0.404 blue: (float)0.024 alpha: (float)1];
```

both ways to compare colors will return YES in your example:

```
[color isEqual:restoredColor]
CGColorEqualToColor(color.CGColor, restoredColor.CGColor)
```

UPDATE: Category for comparison UIColor components

```
@interface UIColor (Compare)

- (BOOL)isEqualToColor:(UIColor *)otherColor;

@end

@implementation UIColor (Compare)

- (BOOL)isEqualToColor:(UIColor *)otherColor {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor);
    float colorOne[4] = {components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]};

    const CGFloat *otherComponents = CGColorGetComponents(otherColor.CGColor);
    float colorTwo[4] = {otherComponents[0], otherComponents[1], otherComponents[2], otherComponents[3]};

    return colorOne[0] == colorTwo[0] && colorOne[1] == colorTwo[1] && colorOne[2] == colorTwo[2] && colorOne[3] == colorTwo[3];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answer, but accepting this since it explains what the underlying issue is + provides a nice solution.

Comment: Noticed that the numbers are doubles and that a simple f at the end of the numbers to make them floats is enough.  The casting will not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26284626/301661

You can try using `CGColorEqualToColor(color.CGColor, restoredColor.CGColor)` to compare colors.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that CGColorEqualToColor will give me the same results.

Answer (score 1):

If you `NSLog` both colors you will see that both colors are actually same!

```
NSLog(@"Color before: %@", color);
NSLog(@"Color after: %@", restoredColor);

// 2015-04-09 13:19:36.640 test[31149:6236981] Color before: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.922 0.404 0.024 1
// 2015-04-09 13:19:36.641 test[31149:6236981] Color after: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.922 0.404 0.024 1
```

so you need to compare each component of the `UIColor` explicitly i.e. `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha`.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622229/2099097)!

---

Quite interestingly, if you log the hashes of these two colors, they too appear to be same

```
NSLog(@"Color Hash before: %lu", (unsigned long)[color hash]);
NSLog(@"Color Hash after: %lu", (unsigned long)[restoredColor hash]);

// 2015-04-09 13:59:06.097 test[31299:6252585] Color before: 137311944
// 2015-04-09 13:59:06.097 test[31299:6252585] Color after: 137311944
```

so you could compare the hashes and get it working.

```
if(color.hash == restoredColor.hash) {
   // ...
}
```

---

As said in the above accepted answer, the `isEqualTo:` doesn't work when you pass in `double` values. `float` values should be passed instead

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922f green:0.404f blue:0.024f alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: I thought about that doing that as well, and this might be the solution that I go with, but it would still be interesting to know what the equality check fails...